# Scoop.it API access in C#

Tags: c#, php

I'm trying to access the Scoop.it API via C# to retrieve posts in topics. It's pretty much straight forward, in PHP, how are objects managed in C# and how to you access the properties?

Here's the php code which i'd like to get a C# equivalent of:

```
$topic = $scoop->topic(24001);
foreach($topic->curatedPosts as $post)
{
  echo $post->title;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an API reference for `Scoop.it` in C#, but I would imagine that they conform to the naming standards in C#.

So the PHP code converted to C# would looke like this:

```
var topic = scoop.Topic(24001);

foreach(var post in topic.CuratedPosts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(post.Title);
}
```

However `echo` in PHP prints something out to the web-page, so I would imagine that you want to replace `Console.WriteLine` with [`Response.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

If you have a class that looks like this, where `Name` is a property:

```
class Topic
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would create an instance of `Topic` like this:

`var topic = new Topic();`

Now you can access the property `Name` like this: `topic.Name`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :-) Among the two options you've provided, what is the best way to approach this considering I'm getting the information through OAUTH?

Comment: I am not quite following what you mean?

Comment: I'm wondering whether to create a Topic class or just use the first approach once i've gotten results from the server